# Python - How to convert escaped sequence to string literals while printing a network path

Tags: python

```
line = "\\\dfslocation\prj\gct\asw\sw_archive"
```

Suppose I got the value of line as above from an argument.

Now I want to print this.

```
print r'%s' %line

'\\\dfslocation\prj\gct\x07sw\sw_archive'
```

But I want to get *\\dfslocation\prj\gct\asw\sw_archive*

How can I get this?

Comment: You need to put the `r` before the string literal you're assigning to `line`, not before the format specifier in `print` -- e.g. `line = r"\\dfslocation\prj\gct\asw\sw_archive"` -- then you can just `print(line)`

Comment: Please check the answer below @Rajib

Comment: This is the probelm. I am not assigning the value to the line. I am getting it from command prompt. That's why I am not able to use r'xxxxx' syntax.

Comment: Actually the script will take input from another interface, not exactly standard command prompt. Hence I can't use above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Make line a raw string literal when assigning the value, instead of doing it in print statement.

```
line = r"\\\dfslocation\prj\gct\asw\sw_archive"

print(line)
```

Comment: This is the probelm. I am not assigning the value to the line. I am getting it from command prompt. That's why I am not able to use r'xxxxx' syntax.

Comment: try this then: `line = input()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping.                                                                                                

Actually the script will take input from another interface, not exactly standard command prompt. Hence I can't use above command.

Comment: I'm sorry, this wasn't mentioned in your question. Couldn't get that point.

Comment: I am sorry too for not mentioning clearly the requirement. 

Any other alternative?

Comment: Can you please edit the question, how you are getting data from other interfaces. Cannot tell without any context.